# Flutter: Creating a user in Firestore using the account created from Firebase Authentication

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

I am creating a flutter app using dart language with Firebase for authentication.

My code for a user signing up is

```
  Future<void> signUp() async {
if(_formKey.currentState.validate()){
  _formKey.currentState.save();
  try{
    AuthResult user = await FirebaseAuth.instance.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email: _email, password: _password);

    Navigator.of(context).pop();
    Navigator.pushReplacement(context,MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context)=> LoginPage()));
  }catch(e){
    print(e.message);
  }
```

Does anyone know how I would use that newly created users credentials to create an entry in the database for user?

I have set up the database with a dummy user which I manually entered but would like to be able to create entries from a user signing up.

Comment: The documentation has instructions on how to add documents to Firestore.  I would start there.  https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data

Comment: in which database you want to add what information ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can get the uid from AuthResult to create a document in Firestore. setData updates the document or in this case, creates one because it doesn't exist. Make sure to install cloud_firestore_package.

```
UserCredential result = await FirebaseAuth.instance.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email: _email, password: _password);
User user = result.user
await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users')
      .doc(user.uid).set({ 'firstName': _firstName})
```

Comment: Thanks for the very helpful answer!!
For anyone else reading this, I added the package & installed it. Then needed to enable multidexing [link](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex)

You can use this line of code for adding multiple values to the one document as per below code:
`code`await Firestore.instance.collection('users').document(user.uid).setData({ 'firstName': _firstName,
'lastName': _lastName,
'userName': _userName})

Comment: result.user is returning an error: LateInitializationError: Field 'user; has not been initialized.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to connect to database. To do this you have to add [cloud_firestore package](http://cloud_firestore%200.13.4) to your project.

On the same page you might find [very nice example](https://pub.dev/packages/cloud_firestore#-example-tab-) how to do it in flutter.

If you seek for more details on the same package page you may find [API reference](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/).

Just study this package, everything should be there.

I hope it will help! Good luck!